# javascript: align absolute div above another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do a combo like thing and I would need to align a div above the input.

How can I calculate the correct `bottom css property` of the list to appear right above the input?

Sample code:

**HTML**

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:150px; left:150px;">
    <input/><span class="btn">V</span>
</div>
<div class="list" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
    width: 10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.list {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var list = $('.list');
    list.show();

    var inputOffset = $('input').offset();

    list.css({
        bottom: inputOffset.top,
        left: inputOffset.left
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lgal/kdez58q9/)

**NOTE:**
The input will work like a filter so the height of the list will change.
I would like to let the browser to keep the list aligned. That's why I would like to set a proper `bottom` value on the list.

Comment: How do you correct anything that's correct? Read your own question and correct, please.

Comment: So you are trying to make the list appear immediately above the input and button?

Answer (score 1):

Use `top` instead of `bottom` and minus the height of the `list` from the `input` position:

```
list.css({
    top: inputOffset.top - list.outerHeight(),
    left: inputOffset.left
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kdez58q9/2/

[image]

Comment: It's nice, but the input will work like a filter so the height of the list will changing. I would like to let the browser to keep the list aligned. That's why I would like to set a proper bottom value on the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/kdez58q9/3/

(Just noticed you wanted the inputs on top...  Here's an updated fiddle with a few tweaks to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/kdez58q9/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <input/><span class="btn">V</span>
    <div class="list" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
    width: 10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.list {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px black;

    /* To make the list on top, change to bottom: 100%;*/
    top: 100%;

    left: 0;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;

    /* If you want the list on top, be sure to add some space above the input */
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $('.list').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Looks nice but my component is not so simple. The list will be rendered as a child of the body but the input and button could be on any level in the dom.

Comment: I see, so the two may not be able to have the same ancestor in the DOM.  I'm not sure what your browser requirements are, but you could look into the HTML5 `datalist` element and input `list` attribute.  Here's a demo from Wufoo http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/05-list.html.  And here is a list of polyfills: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#datalist